# net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Se me esta presentando este error:

net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Cuando ejecuto mi prueba de automatización mi archivo serenity.propeties tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que que quiero hacer es ejecutar la automatización y entiendo que serenity reonoce el sistema operativo en cual se esta haciendo la prueba pero al lanzarlo asi me sale este error, entonces lo que hago es comentarear la parte mac y linux y ya me funciona pero al dejar lo asi tal cual commo esta en la anterior imagen sale este error, he cambiado la versiones y nada no me funciona les agradezo si me pueden ayudar sino como podria hacer una logica donde la automatizaciópn reconozca el sistema operativo y ejecute la prueba sin necesidad de comentarear nada este es mi POM:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTE MI RUNNER
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar

Comment: Hola, tocayo. EL código, los errores y demás, van como texto por favor. Nadie puede replicar desde estas imágenes y los errores pueden estar ahí, sin poderlos ver. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).